# How to add a Name NoteProperty to an object?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

How can add Name NoteProperty for an object? I tried:

```
$a = "This", "Is", "a", "cat"
$a | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name Name  
$a
```

but this doesn't seem to work.

The expected output is:

```
Name
----
This
Is
a
cat
```

Comment: read this http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730946.aspx

Comment: What do you want to achieve? What is your expected output?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the answer to the amended question:

```
$a = "This", "Is", "a", "cat"
$a | Select-Object @{Name='Name'; Expression={$_}}
```

Output, as requested, is

```
Name
----
This
Is
a
cat
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is an example of how to take your example each value in $a, convert it to a PSObject with a Name and Value properties as well as using the Add-Member cmdlet. The ` is for line continuation. Because the Add-Member is being called in a pipeline, the -passThru property was used to pass the object with the new member on.

```
$a | %{ new-object psobject -property @{Name="String"; Value=$_}} `
   | %{ Add-Member -inputObject $_ -passThru -type NoteProperty -name Note -Value Value}
```

I piped the output to | ft -auto to shrink the columns to fit here nicely.

```
Value Name   Note
----- ----   ----
This  String Value
Is    String Value
a     String Value
cat   String Value
```

---

Another way of answering the updated question:
`$a | %{new-object psobject -p @{Name=$_}`
Expected output matches:

```
Name
----
This
Is
a
cat
```